# I keep getting None

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: The question:]

My code:

```
def get_feedback(mark, out_of):
    percentage = int((mark / out_of) * 100)

    if percentage >= 80:
        print("Excellent")
    if 60 < percentage < 70:
        print("Good")
    if 50 < percentage < 59:
        print("Pass")
    if percentage < 50:
        print("Not a pass")
```

I know I have to use a return statement somewhere but I'm not really sure how it works or when to use it. If anyone could help, that would be great thank you!

Comment: Rather than `print("Excellent")` etc. use `grade='Excellent'` etc. and `return grade` at the end. Note you are missing a case for mark between 70 and 79

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_feedback(mark, out_of):
    percentage = int((mark / out_of) * 100)
    remark = ''
    if percentage >= 80:
        remark = "Excellent"
    elif 60 <= percentage <= 79:
        remark = "Good"
    elif 50 <= percentage <= 59:
        remark = "Pass"
    else percentage < 50:
        remark = "Not a pass"
    return remark
```

Some suggestions:

1. I believe you need inclusive range, so include <= instead of <
2. If one condition satisfies, no need to check the rest of the conditions. So instead of using if for every check, use if - elif- else checks.
3. Also your question says the range between 60 and 79 for grade 'Good'. You haven't checked it.

Comment: Did this help? @Amber Woods

Answer (score 0):

Use return in place of print. Example :- return "Excellent".

Answer (score 0):

You can make a variable to represent the value of its condition.

```
def get_feedback(mark, out_of):
    percentage = int((mark / out_of) * 100)

    if percentage >= 80:
        feedback = "Excellent"
    elif 60 < percentage < 70:
        feedback = "Good"
    elif 50 < percentage < 59:
        feedback = "Pass"
    elif percentage < 50:
        feedback = "Not a pass"

    return print(feedback)
```

At the very end, we use return to give us the result of the function. Also, notice that I used elif statements, which are faster than just using if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it :

```
def get_feedback(mark, out_of):
    percentage = int((mark / out_of) * 100)

    if percentage >= 80:
        return "Excellent"
    elif 60 <= percentage <= 79:
        return "Good"
    elif 50 <= percentage <= 59:
        return "Pass"
    else:
        return "Not a pass"
```